# Axon, event store and sql insert

Tags: sql, events, axon

We use Axon 2 to our CQRS-ES

For some (very bad) reasons , we are force to update the content of the eventstore table directly in the database, without using axon. Then we relaunch the axon denormalizer to replay the event and integrate the change in the views

My issue is, when I do it, the newly insert event are not considered by the aggregate ( like there was some sort of cache) .

**How can I ask axon to refresh the cache of the eventstore?**

I know insert event that way is absolutely not a good practice, but we need a workarround.

Answer (score 1):

There is such a cache. To prevent having to replay all events for that aggregate every time an aggregate instance is loaded, Axon stores a snapshot of the aggregate state every so many events

I think your problem will go away when you delete the snapshots. It's probably in a table called `snapshot_event_entry`.

https://legacy-docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/v/2.2/single.html#d5e1274

Comment: My hunch would also be that you've set up snapshots for your Aggregates @sab. Trying out what Mzzl is suggesting here should do the trick.